# Import "urllib3" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to Python and writing a lambda function.
I installed urllib3 using pip but still getting this following error.

[image]

I tried restarting vscode/ uninstall and reinstall but still getting the error.

this is the result when I run pip show urllib3

[image]

what am i missing here?

Comment: is vscode using the same interpreter that `pip` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is more than one python environment on your machine, And the location where you installed the package is inconsistent with the python interpreter you are using now.

You can use **CTRL + SHIFT + P** to open the command palette and search **Python: Select Interpreter** (or click on the *interpreter version* displayed in the lower right corner).

[image]

Select the environment interpreter where you have the `urllib3` package installed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that VS Code uses the same Python Interpreter that you installed this package to.

You can see it here:

[image]

Looks like yours should point to

```
c:\user\###\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\bin\python
```

(or something like that, where your `python` executable file is located)